# Discord JS Bot Don't Move

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, voice

I'm facing a bit of a hiccup with my Discord bot code. So, what I'm trying to do is monitor when someone joins a specific voice channel and then move them to a random voice channel within a designated category. I thought I had everything set up right, and the logs are showing that the bot detects when someone joins the monitored channel. It even logs that the user was detected joining the channel. But then suddenly, out of nowhere, it throws the message "Catégorie cible non trouvée" which means "Target category not found." And this is really puzzling me because I'm sure the category exists.

The logs show the correct new channel ID and the associated category ID, and it seems to be all good up to that point. I've double-checked the category IDs I stored in my monitoredChannels list, and they match the actual IDs in my server. I've also made sure the bot has the right permissions to access the category. So, I'm not sure what's causing this hiccup where the code thinks the category isn't there even though it is. Any ideas on what could be causing this confusion and how to fix it? It's like the bot knows there's a category, but suddenly it doesn't know anymore. :

```
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldState, newState) => {
  const oldChannelId = oldState.channelId;
  const newChannelId = newState.channelId;

  const categoryId = monitoredChannels[newChannelId];

  console.log(`Mise à jour de l'état de l'utilisateur ${newState.member.user.tag}:`);
  console.log(` - Ancien ID du canal : ${oldChannelId}`);
  console.log(` - Nouveau ID du canal : ${newChannelId}`);
  console.log(` - ID de la catégorie : ${categoryId}`);

  if (categoryId && newChannelId !== oldChannelId) {
    console.log(`L'utilisateur ${newState.member.user.tag} a été détecté rejoignant un canal surveillé.`);

    const targetCategory = newState.guild.channels.cache.get(categoryId);

    if (targetCategory && targetCategory.type === 'GUILD_CATEGORY') {
      console.log(` - Catégorie cible trouvée : ${targetCategory.name}`);
      
      const voiceChannels = targetCategory.children.filter(channel => channel.type === 'GUILD_VOICE');
      
      if (voiceChannels.size > 0) {
        console.log(` - Canaux vocaux trouvés dans la catégorie : ${voiceChannels.map(channel => channel.name).join(', ')}`);

        const randomChannel = voiceChannels.random();
        console.log(`Déplacement de l'utilisateur ${newState.member.user.tag} vers le canal : ${randomChannel.name}`);
        newState.member.voice.setChannel(randomChannel)
          .then(() => {
            console.log(`Déplacement réussi de l'utilisateur ${newState.member.user.tag}.`);
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.error(`Erreur lors du déplacement de l'utilisateur ${newState.member.user.tag} : ${error}`);
          });
      } else {
        console.log('Aucun canal vocal trouvé dans la catégorie cible.');
      }
    } else {
      console.log(`Catégorie cible non trouvée.`);
    }
  }
});
```

my logs translated : Update status of user ouin1:

- Old Channel ID: 1144739565505085503
- New Channel ID: 1145098292305338398
- Category ID: undefined
  Update status of user ouin1:
- Old Channel ID: 1145098292305338398
- New Channel ID: 1144739565505085503
- Category ID: 1145102954752393306
  User ouin1 was detected joining a monitored channel.
  Target category not found.

Sorry for my english.

So, I've been trying to get to the bottom of this. First off, I checked the category IDs that I stored in my monitoredChannels list. I meticulously matched them with the actual IDs of the categories in my server, just to ensure that I haven't got any typo or mismatch.

Next, I made sure that my bot has all the permissions it needs to access and view the category. I mean, the bot can even detect the user joining the monitored channel, so it seems to have the basic access it needs.

I've also been digging into the logs, and they look pretty accurate up to the point where it says "Catégorie cible non trouvée" (Target category not found). The logs show the new channel ID and the corresponding category ID, and everything seems spot on.

I even experimented with changing the sequence of operations, thinking that maybe something is getting lost along the way. I double-checked the category type as well, just to make sure it's indeed a 'GUILD_CATEGORY'.

Despite all these checks, I'm still scratching my head over why the bot suddenly throws this error. It's like it knows the category exists and then, all of a sudden, it doesn't. It's a real puzzler, and I'm not sure what else to investigate to get to the bottom of this. Any guidance or insights would be a lifesaver!